# Collision with enemy to inflict damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some problems with Unity. I'm trying to make it so that if an enemy collides with the player, the player loses a health point. My C# code is below.

before you look at the code, I wanted to say that the enemies are rigid bodies so that the object bullets can affect them. I made an extra capsule to be a part of the player body that can be a rigid body so that the code can detect the collision. Do you think that would work? I'm unsure if it's easier for a rigid body to detect another rigid-body collision or if it doesn't care.

```
public class playerhealth : MonoBehaviour {

    private int curHealth;
    private int playerLives;
    public GUIText winText;
    public GUIText healthText;
    public GUIText livesText;

    void Start() {
        curHealth = 3;
        playerLives = 3;
        SetHealthText();
        SetLivesText();
        winText.text = "";
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // where physics codes go
    }

    // HERE'S WHERE THE COLLISIONS STUFF IS

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collider rigidbody) {
        if (rigidbody.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
            curHealth = curHealth - 1;
            SetHealthText();
        }

        if (rigidbody.gameObject.tag == "reloader") {
            playerLives = playerLives - 1;
            SetLivesText();
        }
    }

    // setting GUI TEXT and reloading level

    void SetHealthText() {
        healthText.text = "Health Points: " + curHealth.ToString();
        if (curHealth <= 0) {
            Application.LoadLevel("shootingworld");
            playerLives = playerLives - 1;
        }

        if(curHealth >= 10) {
            playerLives+= 1;
        }

    }

    void SetLivesText() {
        livesText.text = "Lives: " + playerLives.ToString();
        if (playerLives <= 0) {
            winText.text = "GAME OVER";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making a number of assumptions here, some of which are wrong. I'll try to point them out.

Adding a RigidBody to a gameobject is the right idea, but it's the Collider component that determines the shape and size of the object's collision. Consider adding a BoxCollider, SphereCollider or CapsuleCollider to both.

I assume you're having trouble getting the objects to actually collide, this may be the solution.

Also,

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider rigidbody){
```

1. The parameter you've named 'rigidbody' is not guaranteed to be a RigidBody component. According to [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

> The Collision class contains information about contact points, impact velocity etc.
>
> The proper syntax for [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) has a Collision parameter, not a Collider.
>
> To access the rigidbody on the Collider, you'd have to use getcomponent on the object found by the Collider and check if the RigidBody component exists. I'm not sure this is what you're after, but the misleading parameter name should be checked.

Anyway you've got the right idea regarding comparing a Collider's gameobject by tag. All you need to do is enforce the tag on the object, either in the editor or through code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider collision) {
```

}

Collider is used for Ontrigger...

Try this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
```

}

Hope this help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You try to this may help full also

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)

{

}
```

Documentation is :

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html